# Wireless Internet only works on full bars

Tags: router, wireless

I have an odd situation in my current property. When connected to the wireless I need to have full bars or Internet connection is nonexistent. It won't disconnect from the wireless, just the internet stops working.

My initial thoughts were maybe channel contention, so I checked the channel config. I was on 6 so tried both 1 and 11. Same issue persisted. So left it on 11.

It's a virgin horizon box (Ireland) so the Internet is excellent when you can connect, averages about 36Mbps+, just ran a test and got 45.

Has both a 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz. I use the 2.4Ghz generally. Tried the 5Ghz at one stage, but I struggle a bit with range if I'm too far from the router.

Rebooting the box makes no difference. Anyone ever come across this?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

if you are speaking about home WiFI solution please try following software

http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index

Install that on your home router and this will fix the issue. I'm using TPLINK router at home. This helped me.

Good luck

Comment: Consumer-grade equipment, and things like DD-WRT are explicitly off-topic here, as are product or resource recommendations.

Comment: Thanks Viktor. If that doesn't work I'll repost in super user as recommended by Ron.